Issue with Git Integration in JetBrains Fleet Over SSH
I'm using JetBrains Fleet connected to a remote SSH server, and everything works fine except for the Git integration. Whenever I try to perform a git pull, I receive the following error:
Unable to read askpass response from '/tmp/some_temp_file'
WARN: Unable to handle this git request. The default git behavior will be used instead.
  | No matching external auth provider found for the URL "http://your.git.server".
  | External auth provider not found.
unable to read askpass response from '/tmp/some_temp_file'
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-pull(1) for details.
    git pull <remote> <branch>
If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> my-branch

However, using the terminal in Fleet for Git operations works without issues. How can I resolve this problem so that Git integration works properly within the IDE?

Please check if you're using the latest Fleet version available:
https://www.jetbrains.com/fleet/download
Also check if the remote branch exists for you. If not, please create an issue in Fleet's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/FL
and provide the output of git pull --verbose there.
The issue might also be the known problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-73023/unable-to-read-askpass-response-intellij-git-askpass-local.sh
